# Can't get my ComboBox and Button to work. Problem implementing the box with the button

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am trying to get a JComboBox and a JButton to work in tandem by changing the background colour of the JPanel. I am not sure where I am messing up so any help would be much appreciated!

```
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    public class Lab6Part2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

        private String[] BackgroundColours = new String[]{"Green", "Red", "Blue"};
        private JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
        private JComboBox<String> colourSelector = new JComboBox<> (BackgroundColours);
        private JButton changeColour = new JButton ("Change Colour");

        private Lab6Part2() {
            panel.add (colourSelector);
            panel.add (changeColour);

            getContentPane ().add (panel);
            setSize (450, 450);
            setResizable (false);
            setResizable (false);
            setVisible (true);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Lab6Part2 GUI = new Lab6Part2 ();
            GUI.setTitle ("JComboBox and JButton");
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getActionCommand ().equals ("changeColour")){
                if (colourSelector.getSelectedIndex () == 0) {
                    panel.setBackground (Color.GREEN);
                }
                else if (colourSelector.getSelectedIndex () == 1) {
                    panel.setBackground (Color.RED);
                }
                else if (colourSelector.getSelectedIndex () == 2) {
                    panel.setBackground (Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to get a JComboBox and a JButton to work in tandem by changing the background colour of the JPanel

A couple of problems:

1. You never add the ActionListener to the button.

   ```
        changeColour.addActionListener(this);
   ```
2. Even if you add the ActionListener the if condition is wrong:

> private JButton changeColour = new JButton ("Change Colour");
>
> if (e.getActionCommand ().equals ("changeColour")){

Did you verify the if condition is ever true?

The "actionCommand" defaults to the text of the button.

Also, why do you you even use the button. Just add the `ActionListener` to the combo box so the background changes when you select the item instead of forcing the user to also click the button.

Comment: I have no clue, it was one of the requirements that my lecture included in the brief he gave us.

Answer (score 0):

Is there some reason you want to implement ActionListener? I usually find it easier to associate one button with its action.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test extends JFrame {

    private String[] BackgroundColours = new String[]{"Green", "Red", "Blue"};
    private JPanel panel = new JPanel ();
    private JComboBox<String> colourSelector = new JComboBox<String>(BackgroundColours);
    private JButton changeColour = new JButton("changeColour");

    private Test() {
        changeColour.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                changeTheColor();
            }
        });

        panel.add(colourSelector);
        panel.add(changeColour);

        getContentPane().add(panel);
        setSize (450, 450);
        setResizable (false);
        setResizable (false);
        setVisible (true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test GUI = new Test ();
        GUI.setTitle ("JComboBox and JButton");
    }

    public void changeTheColor() {
        if (colourSelector.getSelectedIndex () == 0) {
            panel.setBackground (Color.GREEN);
            System.out.println("g");
        }
        else if (colourSelector.getSelectedIndex () == 1) {
            panel.setBackground (Color.RED);
        }
        else if (colourSelector.getSelectedIndex () == 2) {
            panel.setBackground (Color.BLUE);
        }
    }
}
```